# QGIS 2.18 C++ API: How do I match the scale of vector and OSM tile layers with different crs?

Tags: qgis, api, c++

I'm loading two layers to QGIS maps canvas: the first is a shapefile, and the second is an xml for OSM TileServer.

OSM TileServer - OSM.xml

```
<GDAL_WMS>
    <Service name="TMS">

        <ServerUrl>https://tile.openstreetmap.org/${z}/${x}/${y}.png</ServerUrl>
        <ImageFormat>image/png</ImageFormat>
    </Service>

    <DataWindow>

        <UpperLeftX>-20037508.34</UpperLeftX>
        <UpperLeftY>20037508.34</UpperLeftY>
        <LowerRightX>20037508.34</LowerRightX>
        <LowerRightY>-20037508.34</LowerRightY>

        <TileLevel>18<TileLevel>
        <TileCountX>1</TileCountX>
        <TileCountY>1</TileCountY>
        <YOrigin>top</YOrigin>

    </DataWindow>

    <Projection>EPSG:3857</Projection>
    
    <BlockSizeX>256</BlockSizeX>
    <BlockSizeY>256</BlockSizeY>

    <ZeroBlockHttpCodes>204,303,400,404,500,501</ZeroBlockHttpCodes>
    <ZeroBlockOnServerException>true</ZeroBlockOnServerException>
    
    <BandsCount>3</BandsCount>
    <DataType>byte</DataType>
    <MaxConnections>3</MaxConnections>

</GDAL_WMS>
```

When I load both layers directly in QGIS, the scales match OK and the layers align correctly. When I load them using QGIS C++ API, the scale and position are wrong.

This is the cpp code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"


// QGIS Includes
#include <qgsapplication.h>
#include <qgsproviderregistry.h>
#include <qgsmaplayerregistry.h>
#include <qgsvectorlayer.h>
#include <qgsrasterlayer.h>
#include <qgsmapcanvas.h>

// Globals
QgsMapCanvas * mpMapCanvas;
QList <QgsMapCanvasLayer> myLayerSet;



MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    // Member initializers
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)

{
    ui->setupUi(this);


//  Instantiate Provider Registry
    QgsProviderRegistry::instance("/usr/local/qgis/lib/qgis/plugins");
    QgsApplication::initQgis();

//     Create the Map Canvas
    mpMapCanvas = new QgsMapCanvas(0, 0);
    mpMapCanvas->enableAntiAliasing(true);
    mpMapCanvas->setCanvasColor(QColor(255, 255, 255));
    mpMapCanvas->setCrsTransformEnabled(true);
    mpMapCanvas->freeze(false);
    mpMapCanvas->setVisible(true);

    mpMapCanvas->show();
    
    //load shapfile
    QgsVectorLayer *shapeLayer = new QgsVectorLayer("/home/shp/GSHHS_i_L1.shp", "shp", "ogr");
    QgsMapLayerRegistry::instance()->addMapLayer(shapeLayer, TRUE, TRUE);
    myLayerSet.append(QgsMapCanvasLayer(shapeLayer));
   
  
    // Create a raster layer from a local TMS file
    QgsRasterLayer *tmsLayer = new QgsRasterLayer("./OSM.xml", "OSM_Tile", "gdal", true);
    QgsMapLayerRegistry::instance()->addMapLayer(tmsLayer, TRUE,TRUE); 
    myLayerSet.append(QgsMapCanvasLayer(tmsLayer));

    // Set the Map Canvas Layer Set
    mpMapCanvas->setLayerSet(myLayerSet);

    mpMapCanvas->setExtent(QgsRectangle(120.0, 22.0, 122.0, 25.0));
    mpMapCanvas->refresh();
```

Both layers load OK but with the scale and position mismatch.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution for the above problem.

```
// Check if OTF CRS transformation is enabled
    if (!mapCanvas->hasCrsTransformEnabled())
    {
        // Enable OTF CRS transformation
        mapCanvas->setCrsTransformEnabled(true);
    }
```